# How to smooth from data and plot it with Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a sequence of data points with a significant peak at 1 point

```
1
18
120
196
476
10716
42
43
96
27
61
50
31
15
9
6
11
```

When I plot the data using the webplotlib python package, the 10716 peak distorts the resulting plot in a way so that the smaller values appear almost as a "flat" line. I am describing the problem with my own words since I don't have enough background knowledge about statistics. What is the best way / algorithm to smooth the peak a bit, so the other data becomes "more visible"? I already tried gaussian smoothing ([link](http://www.swharden.com/blog/2008-11-17-linear-data-smoothing-in-python/)), but it appears to not be an appropriate techniqe.

[image]

Comment: Try using a log scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GWW's idea, you could use `plt.semilogy`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.loadtxt('data')
plt.semilogy(x)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The other option to think about is to use a broken Y axis (e.g., http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html). If you need your y-axis to be linear and there is only one or two points "way up there" then you could try this.